# How to use this JQuery function for clearing input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to clear input text using onfocus and onblur inside the input tag, but I'm going to use it on many fields so I found this JQuery function but I can't seem to make it work.

```
$('.default-value').each(function() {

   var default_value = this.value;

   $(this).focus(function(){
           if(this.value == default_value) {
                   this.value = '';
           }
   });

   $(this).blur(function(){
           if(this.value == '') {
                   this.value = default_value;
           }
   }); 
});
```

I tried putting this inside script tag inside the head tag, and I added a class of default-value to the inputs I want to clear but it doesn't work.

so what am I doing wrong ? I don't know javascript and I'm linking to the latest JQuery.

and thanks

Comment: If you're only supporting "good" browsers you can just do `<input type="text" placeholder="my default value"/>`

Comment: Need to include HTML code in your question. Also need to describe what do you want it to do and what it does instead

Comment: I know I 'm using placeholder but I intend to use this instead for older browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you’re re-inventing `@placeholder` here.

Just use HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="foo bar">
```

This is supported in most modern browsers.

Then, use a polyfill to make sure older browsers get similar behavior. I’ve written one in jQuery plugin format, if you’re interested: http://mths.be/placeholder

Use it as follows:

```
$('input, textarea').placeholder();
```

Here’s a demo: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder

Comment: Note that the `placeholder` attribute is an HTML5 feature.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will work because of closure.
You need to remember the default value for each field.
e.g.

```
$('.default-value').each(function() {

   $(this).attr('default_value',$(this).val());

   $(this).focus(function(){
       if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('default_value')) {
               $(this).val('');
       }
   });

   $(this).blur(function(){
       if($(this).val() == '') {
               $(this).val($(this).attr('default_value'));
       }
   }); 
});
```